# How do you expect and verify a private void method call using PowerMockito and TestNG?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng, mockito, powermock

I need to write unit tests against a pre-existing code base using TestNG, Mockito and now PowerMockito, to test private and static methods more easily. I am currently trying to write a test against a private void method in a class that we are testing, but am unable to figure it out. In the normal PowerMock API there are methods called `replayAll()`, `verifyAll()`, and `expectLastCalled()`, which are suitable for most purposes. I just can't find good docs that explain how to do it the PowerMockito way. Any explanations or insights on this would be much appreciated.

Method to test:

```
private void pVMethod(Type param) throws Exception {

    param.setA(StaticClass.methodA().toString());
    param.setB(StaticClass.methodB().toString());

    // getMemo(String label) is in a public class in same package
    param.setC(getMemo("memo.provider"));
    param.setD(getMemo("memo.item"));
        try {
             param.setTimestamp(DataTypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(newjava.util.GregorianCalendar()));
        } catch (SomeException e) {
           ...
          throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

test attempt:

```
@Test(expectedExceptions = Exception.class)
public void pVMethod() throws Exception {
    TestClass testMock = mock(TestClass.class);
    Exception exception = mock(Exception.class);

    // StaticClass staticClassMock = mock(StaticClass.class); ??
    mockStatic(StaticClass.class);

    // when(..) and thenReturn(..) are static imports from PowerMockito library
    when(StaticClass.methodA()).thenReturn("stubStringA");
    when(StaticClass.methodB()).thenReturn("stubStringB");

    doThrow(exception).when(param).setTimestamp(Mockito.any(XMLGregorianCalendar.class));

    // Docs say method name can be inferred via reflection
    Whitebox.invokeMethod(tested, event);

    // this is where things are hairy. testedSpy is defined at the top level
    verifyPrivate(testedSpy).pVMethod(testMock);
}
```

Comment: A little off-topic, but *why* are you testing private methods? Unit tests are supposed to test functionality, not implementation

Comment: My supervisor told me to. I am new to testing on this scale and don't really know why one would or wouldn't do this. But I can say that powermock was made to satisfy the desire for testing private and static methods/fields etc. that would otherwise be inaccessible.

Comment: Well it would probably be helpful if you provided a bit more context. There *are some* legit reasons for testing private methods, but it's more difficult to give advice without the whole picture

Comment: you supervisor is a goofball.  there is no need to test a private method.  Instead test the public, protected, and package access methods and the private methods will be covered.

Comment: Ha, ok. I'll talk to him. But is it unreasonable to try and verify that a private void method was called? i.e. Why is there a method called "verifyPrivate()" and what's the proper way to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is the answer:

In PowerMockito, if you want to verify the behavior of a private void method you use the verifyPrivate() method, but you have to do it like this:

```
verifyPrivate(tested).invoke("privateMethodName", argument);
```

Notice the use of the invoke method, missing from the last line of the OP.

NOTE: You do not have to use a `doNothing().when(mock.privateMethod())` statement, because void methods in mock objects don't do anything by default.

example taken from [here](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13)